Visual Studio disable "right angle bracket" feature
I am using Visual Studio 2022.
In the Visual Studio editor, whenever I am hovering an opening tag on an aspx page, a little right angle bracket menu appeared, and if I accidently click on it it just freeze up for a few seconds and does nothing.
How to disable this feature?

Update: It is to format the code


It looks like that the right angle bracket is used to format the code. It behaves like this in my VS2022 17.11.1. What is the detailed version of your VS?

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.7

I tried settings in Tools->Options->Text Editors->HTML/ASP.NET Web Forms but with no  luck. It seems like a built-in feature and turn on/off  is  not supported at present.
